# Good starting point for quantum Hall matrix models

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, quantum-hall-effect, matrix-model

I am a recent Masters in theoretical condensed matter physics and have experience in working on topological insulators and Weyl semimetals. I have also dabbled a bit in the fractional quantum Hall effect. Recently, I came across an article on quantum Hall matrix models and found it to be quite involved. Can anyone please suggest an easy going introduction for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting with the papers by Matt Lapa. ArXiv:1802.10100 for example.